# Setting interval on componentDidMount in reactjs is an correct approach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have created chat application for my project with Reactjs. For latest update i need to hit the server on each time.  I have used setInterval method for this requirement. Is this approach is correct?

For example,

```
componentDidMount:function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:this.props.url,
      dataType:"JSON",
      type:"GET",
      success:function(data){
        this.setState({data:data});
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's fine, but using setTimeout recursively is generally preferred. It ensures you won't have multiple requests going at once if it takes over a second to complete.

You also probably want to run it once immediately.

Finally, you need to clear the timeout in componentWillUnmount.

```
componentDidMount: function(){
  function tick(){
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: "JSON",
      type: "GET",
      success:function(data){
        this.setState({data: data});

        this.timer = setTimeout(tick, 500);
      }.bind(this)
    });
  };
  tick();
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  clearTimeout(this.timer);
}
```

Comment: Calling `clearTimeout()` in `componentWillUnmount` is important, but not enough. It can happen that the component is unmounted, the timeout is cleared, but there is an outstanding Ajax request that will succeed later, and will try to call `setState()` on an unmounted component.

Comment: @iaretiga you mean clear tha data values right? Like, this.setState({data:""});

Comment: Nope, he means you should store reference to pending request and cancel it when component is unmounted (beside cancelling timeout). In `componentDidMount` do `this.$request = $.ajax({...});`. In `componentWillUnmount` cancel the request by `$request.abort('canceled-by-client');` Without doing this it might happen you will tryi to (e.g.) do `this.setState()` on component which no longer exists